# What does Time tells about mass of an object?

Tags: spacetime, time

According to theory of relativity Time becomes slower in presence of an heavy object. 
And
In theory on concentration it is said when we are in deep concentration our perception of Time changes and it flows faster relative to person in concentration.

So if heavy objects makes time slower, does it mean if time is flowing faster object(s) relative to it are getting lighter in weight?

Comment: *"... it is said when we are in deep concentration our perception of Time changes..."* Your perception of time has nothing to do with physics. You don't become weightless when you sleep, even though you perceive no time.

Comment: @Gangesh it is unclear what you are asking in this question. Also I think you may have some fundamental misunderstandings regarding the nature of general relativity. Try to get a grasp of the basic principles of time dilation first then you may be able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) model of the universe is a mathematical model, and in this all of  time  and space are defined in frameworks. Going from one framework to another requires going through GR transformations.

The variable of time within the framework of a planet close to a large sun, for example,  is defined and stable within it. There is no slowing or getting faster, unless a gravitational wave passes , as the one caught by [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves) a while back.

Only measured from a different framework, by observers outside  the system "planet sun", with other standards of time and space can a slowing down be measured.

Mass is part of the stress energy tensor that defines space time curvatures and is not affected by the relative changes in time or space, mass and energy are that ones that affect time and space, and not vice verso.

Comment: Exactly. Mass affects time and space. So if I rephrase in deep concentration, is it possible that body mass changes that can affect time around that person?

Comment: Not in mainstream physics knowledge which is based on numerous experiments. What your are playing with is metaphysics, not physics. My reply is mainstream physics. if you read my reply carefully, in GR the person will not see changes in time in his/her framework , even while falling into a black hole. Only outside observers see changes, so your analogy does not hold even in metaphysics terms

Comment: Seems like I can't find right place to post. You are right its not entirely physics. Person will not see changes in time while falling into framework, but outside observer will. So outside observer might not see change in person in deep concentration because both are in same framework, but is it that person in concentration might feel different about it?

Comment: The physics analogy does not work. A person cannot see his/her own time change in physics as we know it. It is fixed by entropy and the frequency of radiation from atoms within each observer framework, the person is an observer.

Comment: Person is observer of his time, he wont feel the change, but when can he see when being out of concentrated state  and then realising the difference with current framework? I understand its not entirely physics.

Comment: @Gangesh I cannot answer this. it is metaphysics. not for this forum